# Detecting --prefix location at compile time in C

Tags: c, automake

I'm working with C and Automake tools. Now. I can't find a way to detect the `--prefix` value
so I can search for my config files for my application.

Is there a way to do this? Some `#ifdef` that I can read?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for automake and see what variables it provides you automagically?

Comment: $(PREFFIX) is declared and i added in my Makefile.am AM_CPPFLAGS=-D ROOT=$(PREFIX) but i can't figure how to read it from my C program

Comment: If you are compiling with -DROOT, then you access it with the token 'ROOT'.  eg, printf( "prefix is %s", ROOT ), but you probably want AM_CPPFLAGS = -DROOT="$(PREFIX)"  (note the quotes)

Comment: $(pref9x) whit lower case add the correct string is added but how i read it in my program

Comment: ok. it was like hits 
    -D '_ROOT_="$(prefix)"'
the single and double quotes where needed, then in my code
    ifdef _ROOT_ 
    printf ("valor %s",_ROOT_);   
    #endif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like to answer my own question but thanks to you goys i figured it out how to make it work

```
ok. it was like hits

AM_CPPFLAGS= -D '_ROOT_="$(prefix)"'
```

the single and double quotes where needed, then in my code

```
#ifdef _ROOT_
printf ("valor %s",_ROOT_); 
#endif
```

Comment: `AM_CPPFLAGS = -D_ROOT_=\"${prefix}\"` -- dirs with spaces are not really supported by automake anyway, so you can drop a handful of quotes. Also, it is `AM_CPPFLAGS` not `AM_CPP_FLAGS`, and `_ROOT_` is not the same as `ROOT_`.

Comment: edited, i tried in that way but it didnt work, with the single quotes the double quotes are passed inside the _ROOT_ an its easy to manage it,